# How to track tableview cell's textfield text from viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, protocols, delegation

I would like to observe changes in tableview-cell-textfield's text from related view controller.

I have a text field inside of a cell. It conforms to protocol named 'RouteChangesInfoTableViewCellDelegate'

```
@protocol RouteChangesInfoTableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(NSString *)textNote;
@end
```

Related cell conforms to that protocol.

```
@interface RouteChangesInfoTableViewCell : UITableViewCell <RouteChangesInfoTableViewCellDelegate>
```

Inside of cell's protocol function I am delegating related text without calling.

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(nonnull NSString *)textNote {
    [_routeChangesInfoDelegate textFieldDidChange:self.txtNote.text];
}
```

Related viewcontroller also conforms to the protocol

```
@interface RouteChangesInfoViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, RouteChangesInfoTableViewCellDelegate
```

Inside of viewcontroller  I am trying to delegate as below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    RouteChangesInfoTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RouteChangesInfoTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setRouteChangesInfoDelegate:self];
    return cell;
}
```

Inside of viewcontroller  I am trying to log texts but nothing happens.

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(nonnull NSString *)textNote {
    NSLog(@"DEBUG %@:", textNote);
}
```

- Is this delegation pattern is right?
- If I would like to observe related text change how can I implement the observer (to where)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't quite have the protocol/delegate pattern understood.

You define the protocol correctly:

```
@protocol RouteChangesInfoTableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(NSString *)textNote;
@end
```

but then you're setting your ***cell*** class to conform to that delegate. That's not what you want.

You need to create a delegate property in your cell class. Your **View Controller** will conform to that delegate, and then set the delegate property of the cell to self (the VC).

Then connect an `- (IBAction)textFieldDidChange:(id)sender` in your cell class to the text field. When triggered, ***that*** is where you call the delegate method.

Here is a complete example...

---

**RouteChangesInfoTableViewCell.h**

```
//
//  RouteChangesInfoTableViewCell.h
//  Created by Don Mag on 8/29/20.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@protocol RouteChangesInfoTableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(NSString *)textNote;
@end

@interface RouteChangesInfoTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <RouteChangesInfoTableViewCellDelegate> routeChangesInfoDelegate;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

---

**RouteChangesInfoTableViewCell.m**

```
//
//  RouteChangesInfoTableViewCell.m
//  Created by Don Mag on 8/29/20.
//

#import "RouteChangesInfoTableViewCell.h"

@implementation RouteChangesInfoTableViewCell

- (IBAction)textFieldDidChange:(id)sender {
    UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)sender;
    [_routeChangesInfoDelegate textFieldDidChange:tf.text];
}

@end
```

---

**RouteChangesInfoViewController.h**

```
//
//  RouteChangesInfoViewController.h
//  Created by Don Mag on 8/29/20.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface RouteChangesInfoViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

---

**RouteChangesInfoViewController.m**

```
//
//  RouteChangesInfoViewController.m
//  Created by Don Mag on 8/29/20.
//

#import "RouteChangesInfoViewController.h"
#import "RouteChangesInfoTableViewCell.h"

// conform to RouteChangesInfoTableViewCellDelegate
@interface RouteChangesInfoViewController () <RouteChangesInfoTableViewCellDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation RouteChangesInfoViewController

// delegate method
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(NSString *)textNote {
    NSLog(@"Got text from cell: %@", textNote);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    // make sure table view delegate and datasource are set
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    RouteChangesInfoTableViewCell *cell = (RouteChangesInfoTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    // set the cell's delegate
    cell.routeChangesInfoDelegate = self;
    
    return cell;
}

@end
```

---

**Storyboard with outlet connections...**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="16096" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="DgD-su-IwN">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="16087"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Route Changes Info View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="MLL-TB-u9m">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="DgD-su-IwN" customClass="RouteChangesInfoViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="rmO-xF-6kM">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="896"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="-1" estimatedRowHeight="-1" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Eu3-I2-qTf">
                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="144" width="374" height="618"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                                <prototypes>
                                    <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="cell" id="Wqk-Wo-4g3" customClass="RouteChangesInfoTableViewCell">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="374" height="50.5"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="Wqk-Wo-4g3" id="kNv-M7-XGt">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="374" height="50.5"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <textField opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" textAlignment="natural" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="pwd-WX-JE1">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="8" y="8" width="358" height="34.5"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                                    <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                                                    <connections>
                                                        <action selector="textFieldDidChange:" destination="Wqk-Wo-4g3" eventType="editingChanged" id="oUL-ZP-fB5"/>
                                                    </connections>
                                                </textField>
                                            </subviews>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstItem="pwd-WX-JE1" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="kNv-M7-XGt" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="75C-nB-52g"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="pwd-WX-JE1" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="kNv-M7-XGt" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="OfP-n0-Ttr"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="pwd-WX-JE1" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="sqW-Bc-t50"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="pwd-WX-JE1" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="zrN-ym-Iqw"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                        </tableViewCellContentView>
                                    </tableViewCell>
                                </prototypes>
                            </tableView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="2jf-HS-9oh" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Eu3-I2-qTf" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="100" id="GOH-XI-LDv"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="2jf-HS-9oh" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Eu3-I2-qTf" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="W5X-K6-LdN"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Eu3-I2-qTf" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="2jf-HS-9oh" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="a01-1Z-vDi"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Eu3-I2-qTf" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="2jf-HS-9oh" secondAttribute="top" constant="100" id="b8m-bN-DQ0"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="2jf-HS-9oh"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="tableView" destination="Eu3-I2-qTf" id="MTy-6L-CMb"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="wqw-h7-jEl" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="150" y="2259"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```